# Why is my LinkedList reading an extra node at the end of my list?

Tags: c++, nodes, singly-linked-list

I'm trying to write a function *moveLasttoFront* for my LinkedList class, but it seems to read another Node in before the nullptr at the end of the list.

For example, let's says I have a linked list {0, 1, 2, 8, 3, 4}. I want to run a pointer through the list until it equals nullptr and stop. But instead of stopping after 4, it iterates once more, then stops (I think). Here is my code:

```
  void moveLasttoFront ( ) {
    Node * last = head;
    Node * secLast = nullptr;

    while ( (*last).next != nullptr ) {
        secLast = last;
        last = (*last).next;
    }

    (*last).next = head;
    (*secLast).next = nullptr;
    head = (*last).next;
 }
```

When used on the list above, for example, *secLast* ends up pointing to Node 4 and *last* ends up pointing to 0. I don't understand where this "0" is coming from since there shouldn't be another node after 4? *secLast* should point to 3 and *last* should point to 4.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

P.S. Sorry if this is too vague/I used something wrong. This is my first time asking a question on here :)

Comment: You said you have some doubts about the behaviour of your code. I'm not sure why is it failing, but why not use a debugging tool and manually iterate through your loop? That might help you determine what exactly is causing this error.

Comment: Hmm I did try printing out the values of my pointers throughout the function, but still couldn't figure it out. At this point, I'm thinking the problem may lie elsewhere in my code outside of the function, but as this is for a homework problem and I don't need any external code outside this, I'm not going to worry about it. Now that I have a second opinion, I'm just going to ask my professor about the other issue when I get the chance. Thanks for the help!

Comment: I could try writing a C version if you'd like to. Your code does not seem flawed. My problem is that I do not know C++ well enough to give you a concise answer.

Comment: I see a few bugs in the code, but none of them would cause you to see an extra node. Perhaps creating a [mre] would help you focus on the bug of current interest? Create a short list, output the list to show that it contains what you think it contains, then call `moveLasttoFront()`. Add some more output to demonstrate the problem, perhaps another output of the list and/or showing what `last` and `secLast` point to in `moveLasttoFront()` just before adjusting pointers.

Comment: I have tried some output like that to narrow it down, but didn't try creating a minimal reproducible example. I'll try some more output. Also, you said you saw a few bugs. Just for future reference, are they anything I should be worried about? Thanks!

Comment: @Mctripp When you have the basic functionality working, be sure to test the degenerate cases: a list with no elements and a list with one element.

Comment: Oh okay, good point. Thanks for the advice!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I've made this example in C.

### Main.c

```
#include "linked_list.h"

Node* moveLastToFront(Node* head) {
    Node* secondLast;
    Node* last = head;
    while (last->next != NULL) {
        secondLast = last;
        last = last->next;
    }

    (*secondLast).next = NULL;
    (*last).next = head;
    head = last;

    return head;
}

int main(void) {
    Node* head = NULL;
    for (int i = 1; i < 10; i++)
        head = addnode(head, i);

    listprint(head);
    printf("\n");
    head = moveLastToFront(head);
    listprint(head);

    return 0;
}
```

### linked_list.h

```
#ifndef LINKED_LIST_H
#define LINKED_LIST_H

typedef struct Node {
    int data;
    struct Node* next;
} Node;

Node *addnode(Node* node, int data);
void listprint(Node* node);
void freelist(Node* node);

#endif // LINKED_LIST_H
```

### linked_list.c

```
#include "linked_list.h"
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

Node* addnode(Node* node, int data) {
    if (node == NULL) {
        node = malloc(sizeof (Node));

        node->data = data;
        node->next = NULL;
    }
    else
        node->next = addnode(node->next, data);

    return node;
}

void freelist(Node* node) {
    if (node != NULL) {
        freelist(node->next);
        free(node);
    }
}

void listprint(Node* node) {
    static int i = 0;
    if (node != NULL) {
        printf("Node [%d] points to node [%d] which contains: %d\n", i, i + 1, node->data);
        i++;
        listprint(node->next);
    }
    else
        i = 0; // Reset i in case function is called again with another list
}
```

---

Output:

```
Node [0] points to node [1] which contains: 1
Node [1] points to node [2] which contains: 2
Node [2] points to node [3] which contains: 3
Node [3] points to node [4] which contains: 4
Node [4] points to node [5] which contains: 5
Node [5] points to node [6] which contains: 6
Node [6] points to node [7] which contains: 7
Node [7] points to node [8] which contains: 8
Node [8] points to node [9] which contains: 9

Node [0] points to node [1] which contains: 9
Node [1] points to node [2] which contains: 1
Node [2] points to node [3] which contains: 2
Node [3] points to node [4] which contains: 3
Node [4] points to node [5] which contains: 4
Node [5] points to node [6] which contains: 5
Node [6] points to node [7] which contains: 6
Node [7] points to node [8] which contains: 7
Node [8] points to node [9] which contains: 8
```

If you have any doubts feel free to ask!

Comment: Thank you! This is pretty helpful to see. One thing I noticed from looking at your program was that you set head=last in moveLastToFront, while I set head=(*last).next. This solved part of my problem, but I'm still getting a "0" carrying over to the beginning of the list rather than the actual last Node. {0, 1, 2, 3, 4} still goes to {0, 0, 1, 2, 3}

Comment: The question is tagged C++, not C. It's usually undesirable for an answer to change the language of choice.